# opening an image on a new tab

Tags: php, html

hey so i'm running into the problem that i want to make a image open on a new tab, but with the way i open images into the code i don't know how to do it

```
<?php
$all_files = glob("commissions/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($all_files); $i++)
{
    $image_name = $all_files[$i];
    $supported_format = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png');
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_format))
    {
        echo ' <a href="URL" target="_blank"><img class="comimg" src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'" /></a>';
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us what error you get or what is exactly not working as you expected ?

Answer (score 0):

just put the image''

```
  if (in_array($ext, $supported_format))
   {
     echo ' <a href="'.$image_name.'" target="_blank">Image Name Here</a>';
   } else {
       continue;
   }
```

or

```
if (in_array($ext, $supported_format))
       {
         echo ' <a href="'.$image_name.'" target="_blank"><img class="comimg" src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'" /></a>';
       } else {
           continue;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a new page to display your images for example show-image.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['image']) && file_exists("commissions/".$_GET['image'])) {
 $image_name = $_GET['image'];
 $supported_format = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png');
 $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
 if (in_array($ext, $supported_format))
  {
     echo '<img class="comimg" src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'" />';
  } else {
      echo "no preview available";
  }
 } else echo "image not found";
```

then change your links to point to that page

```
   echo ' <a href="show-image.php?image='.$image_name.'" target="_blank"><img class="comimg" src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'" /></a>';
```

Comment: but the thing is, i want the link to the page to be created together with the image upload, is that also possible?

Comment: yes, the new image is displayed after the upload